# Embedded Bootstrap Jboss Datasource Driver Issue

Tags: maven, jboss, junit

I've been working on this problem for a couple days, and it's driving me crazy.

I've got a piece of somewhat legacy code, using Jboss 4.2.3.  I recently converted the project to Maven for dependency management, but the unit tests which were written for the project need the datasource.  When I disable the tests, the program works just fine, but when I enable the tests, it throws the following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I have the jboss embedded dependencies listed in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>beta3.SP12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>beta3.SP12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-all</artifactId>
    <version>beta3.SP12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>thirdparty-all</artifactId>
    <version>beta3.SP12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>src/test/bootstrap</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <argLine>-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true</argLine>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
        <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In src/test/bootstrap/deploy I've placed the dev-ds.xml file, which is being picked up by the container.

```
Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=jdbc/theDS' to JNDI name 'java:jdbc/theDS'
```

My dev-ds file looks like this (with some obfuscation, please excuse any typos)

```
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>jdbc/theDS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:DEVDB</connection-url>
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

The actual test itself uses Mockito to try to get the datasource.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception 
    {
    if( ! containerRunning )
        {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = Bootstrap.getInstance();
        bootstrap.bootstrap();
        containerRunning = true;
        }
    }

@Before
public void setUp()
    {
    MyDAO dao = spy( new MyDAO() );
    try
        {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        dao.datasource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup( "java:jdbc/theDS" );
        Connection conn = dao.datasource.getConnection(); //bang, we're dead
        }
```

Exception:

```
Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)); - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Failed to register driver for: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
```

As I mentioned, the code works when it's run, so I know that the ojdbc6.jar is located in the ${jboss.dir}/server/default/lib.  But just to be sure, I tried adding it to the build path, and I've tried the "order and export" in Eclipse, all to no avail.  I'm running out of ideas.  Let me know if I've missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind a of work around, but it will work for now.  In the maven-surefire-plugin I added the following line.

```
<additionalClasspathElement>lib/ojdb6.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
```

I also made a test constructor for the DAO objects, since the datasource creation was done in the constructor, and Mockito doesn't override that.  All that work to find out that the tests probably never worked in the first place. :)

To help anyone who's stumbled here, in the bootstrap, it will not allow you to bind the anything in the InitialContext to the global scope.  I.E.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.createSubcontext( "jdbc/theDS" ); //Does not work
```

From what I gathered scouring the internet, embedded jboss only knows about the environment scope.